# Execute script after email send in php

Tags: php, forms, smtp, phpmailer

Hello I am sending email with smtp. Email is sending schusses fully but the script after email send script is not working. can anyone help me with this ?

Emails are sending successfully but in return the script is not executing.

Also email take like 2 seconds to send but it does not matter the mail issue is script is not working

Here's code

```
<?php
require 'include/dbconfig.php';


require_once "vendor/autoload.php";


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//PHPMailer Object

$mail = new PHPMailer(); //Argument true in constructor enables exceptions
            // SMTP configuration
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;   
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
            $mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
            $mail->Password = "emailpassword";
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
            $mail->Port = 587;


            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'Sabir'); 
          
            $mail->addAddress("test@gmail.com");
           
           
            $mail->Subject = "Test";
            $mail->Body = "Test Email";
            $email_sent=$mail->send();
                    if(!$email_sent) { ?>
                       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                     alert('Something went wrong');
                    </script><?php
                } else { ?>
                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                     alert('Thank you for the message');
                    </script>
                    <?php
                    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

you can cut your statements a bit down:

```
                 $email_sent=$mail->send();
                    if(!$email_sent) { ?>
                   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                 alert('Something went wrong');
                </script><?php
            } else { ?>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                 alert('Thank you for the message');
                </script>
                <?php
                }
```

It should look and work like that:

```
$email_sent = $mail->send();
                if(!$email_sent) {}else {}
```

Also you don´t need to make all this breaks,
just put your js in a echo and remove that:

```
language="javascript"
```

instead go for:

```
  echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong');</script>";
```

So it would look like that:

```
     $email_sent = $mail->send();
                if(!$email_sent) { 
    echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Thank you for the message');</script>";
}
```

**Edit**

Nearly forgot!

Now we have cleared the code a bit,
but it won´t work like that.

You will need to adjust your form aswell with:

```
onclick or onsubmit
```

Or go for an ajax call:

```
$('#mailform').on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({ 
            data:    {data_field: 'value'},
            type:    'post',
            url:     '/script.php',
            success: function(r) {$('#thepoup').removeClass('hidden')},
            error:   function(r) {alert('error'); console.log(r)}
        });
});
```

Comment: This will cause duplicate messages to be sent because you're calling `send()` twice. The original code was correct for that.